# Approximating the normal CDF for $0 \leq x \leq 7$

Tags: numerical-methods, normal-distribution, approximation, rational-functions

In answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23119456/2421256, an approximation of the complementary normal CDF (ie $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_x^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt$) was given for $0 \leq x \leq 7$ using a rational function as follows :
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \frac{N_0 + N_1 x + ... + N_6 x^6}{M_0 + M_1 x + ... + M_7 x^7} $$

How can one derive such an approximation,**without relying on an already implemented approximation** (*ie* no methods based on curve fitting), and a bound for the absolute error ?

**EDIT** : I added a bounty because I believe this question is not at all trivial.

**EDIT 2** : I'm adding here what I've been able to do for now. Indeed, as Ian pointed out, for $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$ a good approximation of the normal CDF can be derived easily, by using a Taylor series expansion of $e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$ and integrating it term by term between $0$ and $x$.

For $\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq 7$, I proved, using Mill's inequality and the fact that $\frac{\int_x^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt}{x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}$ is increasing in $x$, that $$\mathbb{P} \left( Z > x \right) \leq \frac{x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{98 \pi} $$, which yields an error smaller than $2.39 \times 10^{-3} $, but it is far from the precision yielded by the rational approximation above (around $10^{-16}$, checked numerically since I don't have a rigourous bound for it).

**EDIT 3** : if it's of help, the target error is something smaller than $10^{-9} $.

Comment: For slightly larger $x$ (I think it turns out to be $x>\sqrt{2}$), you can derive the bounds $p(x) e^{-x^2/2} \leq F(x) \leq q(x) e^{-x^2/2}$, where $p,q$ are rational functions that can be computed explicitly. This means that $e^{x^2/2} F(x)$ is "asymptotically like" a rational function. (Try plotting it; past about $x=30$ you get floating point issues, but until then you can see what I mean.) You can then try to approximate this instead, and then stitch together the approximation close to $0$ and close to $\infty$ using Pade approximation or similar techniques.

Comment: @Ian the problem is that most techniques I've seen seem to come from linear regression or other methods to fit a polynomial or rational function to an already approximated normal cdf. Plus in that case the error is only bounded numerically. As for the Padé technique, I'm not sure at all I understand it and would like to have some good reference for someone new to the technique.

Comment: @BS. I don't have access to the paper, but references in literature suggest that the following paper may be of interest, giving an approximation precisely for the interval you are interested in: P. A. P. Moran, "Calculation of the normal distribution function", *Biometrika 67* (1980), pp. 675-677. The approximation seems to be an expansion in trig functions best I can tell.

Comment: C implementation of Moran is `double cdf (double z) { double pi = 3.14159265358979323; double sqrt2 = sqrt (2.0); double sum = 0.0; for (int k = 1; k <= 12; k++) { sum += (1.0 / k) * exp (-k * k / 9.0) * sin (k * z * sqrt2 / 3); } return 0.5 + (z / (3 * sqrt2) + sum) / pi; }` , accurate to about nine decimal places. Literature references indicate Moran's work is based on [Anthony J. Strecok, "On the Calculation of the Inverse of the Error Function", *Math. Comp.*, v. 22, 1968, pp. 144-158.](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-136/S0025-5718-1976-0421040-7/S0025-5718-1976-0421040-7.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong paper in my preceding comment. The Strecok paper I referenced can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-101/S0025-5718-1968-0223070-2/S0025-5718-1968-0223070-2.pdf)

Comment: @BS. Also of interest may be this paper: George Marsaglia, "Evaluating the Normal Distribution", *Journal of Statistical Software*, July 2004, Volume 11, Issue 4, pp. 1-11. The approximation for $\Phi$ is claimed to be accurate to almost double precision over your targeted interval using a very simple expansion. Online copy can be found [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v011i04/v11i04.pdf)

Comment: @njuffa thank you for the extensive list of references, I'll make sure to read all of them !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a definitive answer, but hopefully points you in the right direction. The short of it is, I don't know how the coefficients were derived, but it is likely related to some Pade, Remez, interpolating, or least-squares approximant. Read on for details.

The function we're talking about is
$$
Q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\;dt = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right), 
$$
for $x>0$, where $\operatorname{erfc}$ is the complimentary error function.

The link you provide gives code for an approximation of the following form, slightly different than how it was stated in the original question (note the lack of normalization by $\sqrt{2\pi}$ and a different form of the polynomials).
$$
\tilde{Q}(x) = e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \frac{(((((N_6 z+N_5)z+N_4)z+N_3)z+N_2)z+N_1)z+N_0}{((((((M_7 z+M_6)z+M_5)z+M_4)z+M_3)z+M_2)z+M_1)Z+M_0}
$$
Why do we pick this form? Well, asymptotically, the $Q$ function is well approximated by $\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. [See here for details on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion). This justifies factoring out the asymptotic behavior and looking for a rational approximation of what remains. If we factored out the asymptotic form, we could approximate what remains with something that goes to $1$ for large $x$, i.e., something with equal order in the numerator and denominator. If we leave that extra factor of $x$ in the denominator from the asymptotic piece, we can account for it by absorbing it into the denominator of the rational function, giving one higher degree in the denominator polynomial. The same goes for the factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$, it gets absorbed in to the approximation.

Now, how on earth did Hart come up with those $N_i$ and the $M_j$ coefficients? I thought it was by requiring that the Taylor series of $\tilde{Q}(x)e^{x^2/2}$ matches that of $Q(x)e^{x^2/2}$ at some a point, up to a high enough order to uniquely determine all the coefficients. This is the [Pade approximation technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant), and you should be able to find more about the [error bounds for approximations resulting from this technique](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609094v1.pdf). I used Mathematica to calculate these below.

I thought that surely, if you calculate that Pade approximant around $x=0$, and scale the coefficients to match this weird $M_0=440.413735824752$ (Pade approximants are usually normalized so that the constant term in the denominator is $1$) you'd get the formula. Instead, I get:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
i & N_i & M_i\\
0 & 220.207 & 440.414\\
1 & 152.909 & 711.438\\ 
2 & 95.568 &  525.241 \\
3 & 23.168 &  234.066 \\
4 & 4.6336 &  61.9813\\
5 & 0.34752 &  10.2661 \\
6 & 0.154453 & 1.04799 \\
7 & {}  & 0.048886
\end{array}
$$

It's a similar pattern to Hart's numbers, and the values are all in the same ballpark as Hart's numbers, but it is not a match. Then I thought that there is this weird breakpoint in the code that appears to be $\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 7.07$. This lead me down the path of looking to see if the Pade approximant near $\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}}$ or at the halfway point of the interval, $\frac{10}{2\sqrt{2}}$, appropriately scaled, gave Hart's original coefficients. They don't.

So here are some possibilities.

1. Hart's coefficients are for a Pade approximant around SOME point on the interval $[0,10/\sqrt{2}]$, and I don't have the patience to find which point.
2. Hart used some other method to generate these coefficients, and they don't correspond to a Pade approximant at all. One candidate is the Remez algorithm for rational functions, which should guarantee the error oscillates equally across the domain of approximation. Another candidate is that the coefficients are derived from an interpolation between some fixed points with known values of the domain. Yet another is a least-squares fit between the rational approximant a a bunch of known values of the function.

This has been a long winded answer, and boils down to "I don't know". But I hope the techniques I mentioned can be fruitful avenues for you to continue looking into this. I would finally suggest getting the original "Algorithm 5666 for the error function" and seeing if there is an explanation of the methodology in book in which it appears.

Comment: Excellent answer and very useful insights. Props also for the references !

Comment: I have not checked the introductory chapters in Hart, et. al. in many years, but am reasonably certain that the authors used variants of the Remez algorithm to derive the coefficients for many (probably most) minimax approximations in the book, both the polynomial and the rational ones. I understood the present question as a request for alternative approximations not derived by such purely numerical methods as the Remez algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Required rational approximation for $\operatorname{erfc}$ function can be constructed analytically, on the basis of known Maclaurin series
$$\sqrt\pi ze^{z^2}\operatorname{erfc}z = v,$$
$$v=1-\frac{1\cdot3}{2z^2}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{(2z^2)^2}-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{(2z^2)^3}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9}{(2z^2)^4}-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot11}{(2z^2)^5}+\cdots,$$
and
$$(1+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\dots)^{-1}=$$
$$=1-a_1x+(a_1^2-a_2)x^2+(-a_1^3+2a_1a_2-a_3)x^3+(a_1^4-3a_1^2a_2+2a_1a_3+a_2^2-a_4)x^4+\dots$$
Then
$$v=1+\frac1{v_1},\quad v_1=\frac{1}{v-1}
$$$$v_1=\left(-\frac{1\cdot3}{2z^2}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{(2z^2)^2}-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{(2z^2)^3}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9}{(2z^2)^4}-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot11}{(2z^2)^5}+\dots\right)^{-1}
$$$$ = -\frac{2z^2}3\left(1 - \frac{5}{2z^2} + \frac{5\cdot7}{(2z^2)^2} - \frac{5\cdot7\cdot9}{(2z^2)^3} + \frac{5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot11}{(2z^2)^4}+\dots\right)^{-1}
$$$${= -}\frac{2z^2}3\left(1 + \frac{5}{2z^2} + \frac{5^2-5\cdot7}{(2z^2)^2} + \frac{-(-5)^3+2\cdot(-5)\cdot(5\cdot7)-(-5\cdot7\cdot9)}{(2z^2)^3}+ \frac{(-5)^4-3\cdot(-5)^2\cdot(5\cdot7)+2\cdot(-5)\cdot(-5\cdot7\cdot9)+(5\cdot7)^2-5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot11}{(2z^2)^4}+\dots\right)$$
$$= -\frac{2z^2}3 - \frac53 + \frac{10}{3\cdot2z^2} - \frac{30}{(2z^2)^2}+ \frac{1090}{3(2z^2)^3}+\dots,$$
$$v_1{= -}\frac{2z^2}3 - \frac53 + \frac1{v_2},\quad v_2=\dfrac1{v_1 + \dfrac{2z^2}3 + \dfrac53}$$
$$v_2 = \left(\frac{10}{3\cdot2z^2} - \frac{30}{(2z^2)^2} + \frac{1090}{3\cdot(2z^2)^3}+\dots\right)^{-1} = \frac{3\cdot2z^2}{10}\left(1 - \frac{9}{2z^2} + \frac{109}{(2z^2)^2}+\dots\right)^{-1}$$
etc.

The advantage of this approach - that we can indefinitely increase the accuracy of the basic series, and thus - the approximation accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

[ Edited ]
In Maple, you can do it like this (which uses the Remez algorithm):

```
with(numapprox):
Digits:= 20:
F:= 1/2 - erf(x/sqrt(2))/2: 
Fapp:= minimax(F,x=0..7,[9,9],1,'maxerr');
```

Output:

```
    Fapp := (0.0080517962284732651617 + (-0.010275984418814906351 + 
 (0.0057508901000869300345 + (-0.0018400187444236603087 +
 (0.00036700227787513526080 + (-0.000046447368225878900155 + 
 (3.5900991299615081445*10^(-6) + (-1.4757129537825456546*10^(-7) +
 (1.7071457409545982509*10^(-9) + 4.9555358540812079443*10^(-11)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)/
(0.016103592460016837118 + (-0.007703161391705450475 + 
(0.005355553375678378021 + (-0.001548442376486788873 + 
(0.000523090265546298297 + (-0.0000669104367251402844 + 
(6.57286840236719580*10^(-6) + (3.652261758671149217*10^(-6) + 
(-8.192546878366383619*10^(-7) + 
1.5161252187912221743*10^(-7)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)
```

The (approximate) maximum error:

```
maxerr;
```

9.773441086*10^(-11)

To verify, plot the difference:

```
plot(Fapp-F,x=0..7);
```

[image]

Comment: a bit late, but I tried this with x=1 and the result was 0.261578291865162, but the normal cdf is 0.8413447460685429

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I was approximating a different function there.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

The Stackoverflow answer linked in the question cites this publication: Graeme West, "Better approximations to cumulative normal functions", *Wilmott Magazine*, Issue 9, May 2005, pp. 70-76. That publication in turn states that this approximation to the CDF of the standard normal distribution is derived from approximation 5666 in Hart, et al., *Computer Approximation*, Wiley 1968. This reference work is still widely used by math function implementers despite its age. I myself have a copy of the corrected reprint from 1978 published by Krieger Publishing.

Approximation 5666 is a rational minimax approximation (or, in the terminology used in the book, a least maximum approximation) to $\mathrm{erfc(x)}$ on $[0, 10]$, and specifically $\mathrm{erfc}(x) \approx e^{-x^2}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$. Approximations in the book are designed to minimize *absolute error* rather than relative error unless noted otherwise. The function overview on page 140 shows that approximation 5666 offers a precision of $16.36$ decimal digits, which makes it suitable for double-precision computation. I verified through testing that the approximation has minimax properties, is designed to minimize absolute error, and achieves the stated precision.

In section 3.6 of the book the authors briefly explain that the rational approximations in the book were computed using a variant of the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm) (the spelling "Remes" is used in the book, which is how Remez himself transcribed his name from Cyrillic letters when he published his algorithm in a French journal in 1934).

Since the CDF of the standard normal distribution $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{erfc}\left( -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}x\right)$, one can straight-forwardly derive an approximation for $\Phi(x)$ by dividing the coefficients by the appropriate power of $\sqrt{2}$. The original coefficients of approximation 5666 are (decimal exponent, fraction):

```
P00  (+3) +.44041 37358 24752 23325 269
P01  (+3) +.62568 65357 69683 00613 5193
P02  (+3) +.44831 71659 91483 44293 45063
P03  (+3) +.19184 01405 87966 85752 39030 1
P04  (+2) +.50991 69762 82532 03795 66952 3
P05  (+1) +.79239 29828 74154 48527 19403 9
P06  (+0) +.56419 99455 98257 48305 03867 3
Q00  (+3) +.44041 37358 24752 21430 599
Q01  (+4) +.11226 40220 17704 65788 53681
Q02  (+4) +.12746 67266 75766 22866 58026 8
Q03  (+3) +.83881 03654 78406 44197 94177 8
Q04  (+3) +.34712 29288 11784 33142 90780 57
Q05  (+2) +.90872 71120 35370 36259 55073 71
Q06  (+2) +.14045 33730 54611 38298 47322 587
Q07  (+1) +.1
```

By the substitution mentioned above, this approximation to $\mathrm{erfc}(x)$ on $[0, 10]$ is then transformed into the approximation of $\Phi(x)$ on $[0, 10/ \sqrt{2}]$. It is not clear whether this upper interval bound in West's paper was selected in error, because based on the substitution the approximation to $\Phi(x)$ is valid on the *wider* interval $[0, 10\sqrt{2}]$.

Based on the substitution the scale factor becomes $e^{-x^{2}/2}$, and the coefficients of the rational approximation are as follows: $\mathtt{N0} = \mathtt{P00} / 2$, $\mathtt{N1} = \mathtt{P01} / (2\sqrt{2})$, $\mathtt{N2} = \mathtt{P02} / 4$, $\mathtt{N3} = \mathtt{P03} / (4\sqrt{2})$, $\mathtt{N4} = \mathtt{P04} / 8$, $\mathtt{N5} = \mathtt{P05} / (8\sqrt{2})$, $\mathtt{N6} = \mathtt{P06} / 16$, and in the same fashion $\mathtt{M0} = \mathtt{Q00}$, $\mathtt{M1} = \mathtt{Q01} / \sqrt{2}$, $\mathtt{M2} = \mathtt{Q02} / 2$, $\mathtt{M3} = \mathtt{Q03} / (2\sqrt{2})$, $\mathtt{M4} = \mathtt{Q04} / 4$, $\mathtt{M5} = \mathtt{Q05} / (4\sqrt{2})$, $\mathtt{M6} = \mathtt{Q06} / 8$, $\mathtt{M7} = \mathtt{Q07} / (8\sqrt{2})$.

The book provides ten different rational approximations (approximations 5660 through 5669) to $\mathrm{erfc}(x)$ on $[0, 10]$ with precision ranging from $2.21$ to $23.45$ decimal digits.